# Join two collections with MapReduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, mapreduce, lookup, nosql

I already know that MongoDB doesn't support join operations, but i have to simulate a `$lookup` (from the aggregation framework) with the `mapReduce` paradigm.

My two collections are:

```
// Employees sample 
{
  "_id" : "1234",
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : "Bush",
  "departments" : 
  [ 
    { "dep_id" : "d001", "hire_date" : "date001" },
    { "dep_id" : "d004", "hire_date" : "date004" }
  ]
}
{ 
  "_id" : "5678", 
  "first_name" : "Johny", 
  "last_name" : "Cash", 
  "departments" : [ { "dep_id" : "d001", "hire_date" : "date03" } ] 
}
{ 
  "_id" : "9012", 
  "first_name" : "Susan", 
  "last_name" : "Bowdy", 
  "departments" : [ { "dep_id" : "d004", "hire_date" : "date04" } ] 
}

// Departments sample 
{
  "_id" : "d001",
  "dep_name" : "Sales",
  "employees" : [ "1234", "5678" ]
},
{
  "_id" : "d004",
  "name" : "Quality M",
  "employees" : [ "1234", "9012" ]
}
```

And actually I'd like to have a result like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "1234",
  "value" : 
  {
    "first_name" : "John",
    "departments" :
    [
      { "dep_id" : "d001", "dep_name" : "Sales" },
      { "dep_id" : "d004", "dep_name" : "Quality M" }
    ]
  }
}
{ 
  "_id" : "5678", 
  "value" : 
  { 
    "first_name" : "Johnny", 
    "departments" : [ { "dep_id" : "d001", "dep_name" : "Sales" } ]
  } 
}
{ 
  "_id" : "9012", 
  "value" : 
  { 
    "first_name" : "Susan", 
    "departments" : [ { "dep_id" : "d004", "dep_name" : "Quality M" } ] 
  } 
}
```

The common fields are `dep_id` (from Employees) and `_id` (from Departments).

My code is the next one, but it doesn't work as I need.

```
var mapD = function() {
  for (var i=0; i<this.employees.length; i++) {
    emit(this.employees[i], { dep_id: 0, dep_name: this.dep_name });
  }
}

var mapE = function() {
  for (var i=0; i<this.departments.length; i++) {
    emit(this._id, { dep_id: this.departments[i].dep_id, dep_name: 0 });
  }
}

var reduceLookUp = function(key, values) {
  var result = {dep_id: 0, dep_name: 0};
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    if (value.dep_name !== null && value.dep_name !== undefined) {
      result.dep_name = values.dep_name;
    }
    if (value.dep_id !== null && value.dep_id !== undefined) {
      result.dep_id = value.dep_id;
    }
  });
  return result;
};

db.Departments.mapReduce(mapD, reduceLookUp, { out: { reduce: "joined" } });
db.Employees.mapReduce(mapE, reduceLookUp, { out: { reduce: "joined" } });
```

I'll really apreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your problem `first_name` can be fetched only from `Employees` collection and `dep_name` can be fetched only from `Departments` collection.

You can achieve it both with MapReduce and aggregation framework.

**1. MapReduce solution**

If you modify your map and reduce functions as follows

```
var mapD = function() {
  for (var i=0; i<this.employees.length; i++)
    emit(this.employees[i], { dep_id: this._id, dep_name: this.dep_name });  
}

var mapE = function() { emit(this._id, { first_name: this.first_name }); }

var reduceLookUp = function(key, values) {
  var results = {};
  var departments = [];
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    var department = {};
    if (value.dep_id !== undefined) department["dep_id"] = value.dep_id;
    if (value.dep_name !== undefined) department["dep_name"] = value.dep_name;
    if (Object.keys(department).length > 0) departments.push(department);
    if (value.first_name !== undefined) results["first_name"] = value.first_name;
    if (value.departments !== undefined) results["departments"] = value.departments;
  });
  if (Object.keys(departments).length > 0) results["departments"] = departments;
  return results;
}
```

then first MapReduce call

```
db.Departments.mapReduce(mapD, reduceLookUp, { out: { reduce: "joined" } });
```

will insert into `joined` collection

```
{ 
  "_id" : "1234", 
  "value" : 
  {
    "departments" : 
    [ 
      { "dep_id" : "d001", "dep_name" : "Sales" }, 
      { "dep_id" : "d004", "dep_name" : "Quality M" } 
    ] 
  }
}
```

while second call

```
db.Employees.mapReduce(mapE, reduceLookUp, { out: { reduce: "joined" } });
```

should insert

```
{ "_id" : "1234", "value" : { "first_name" : "John" } }
```

but, according to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#out-options), `reduce` output option will

> Merge the new result with the existing result if the output collection
>   already exists. **If an existing document has the same key as the new
>   result, apply the reduce function to both the new and the existing
>   documents and overwrite the existing document with the result**

Thus, reduce function will be called again in your case with parameters

```
key = "1234",
values =
[
  {
    "departments" : 
    [ 
      { "dep_id" : "d001", "dep_name" : "Sales" }, 
      { "dep_id" : "d004", "dep_name" : "Quality M" } 
    ] 
  },
  { "first_name" : "John" }
]
```

and final result is

```
{ 
  "_id" : "1234", 
  "value" : 
  { 
    "first_name" : "John", 
    "departments" : 
    [ 
      { "dep_id" : "d001", "dep_name" : "Sales" }, 
      { "dep_id" : "d004", "dep_name" : "Quality M" }
    ] 
  } 
}
```

**2. Aggregation framework solution**

A better solution for your problem is to use [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) instead of Map-Reduce. Here you would use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage to fetch some data from `Employees`

```
db.Departments.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$employees" },
  { 
    $lookup: 
      { 
        from: "Employees", 
        localField: "employees", 
        foreignField: "_id", 
        as: "employee"
      }
  },
  { $unwind: "$employee" },
  { 
    $group: 
      { 
        "_id": "$employees",
        "first_name": { $first: "$employee.first_name" }, 
        "departments": { $push: { dep_id: "$_id", dep_name: "$dep_name" } } 
      } 
  } 
]);
```

that will result into

```
{ 
  "_id" : "1234",
  "first_name" : "John",
  "departments" : 
    [ 
      { "dep_id" : "d001", "dep_name" : "Sales" }, 
      { "dep_id" : "d004", "dep_name" : "Quality M" } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: How it should be if in the result I want the first_name field of Employee as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need it with `map` and `reduce` functions. :(