# How merge two collections in MongoDB by using Map/Reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'd like to merge these two collections, and it has "name" variable as the common field.

```
// product collections   

db.products.insertOne( { name : "iPhone 5", Price : 600, company : "Apple"}) 
db.products.insertOne( { name : "Galaxy Note9", Price : 900, company : "samsung"}) 
db.products.insertOne( { name : "LG V40 ThinQ", Price : 800, company : "LG"}) 
db.products.insertOne( { name : "Watch", Price : 400, company : "Apple"}) 
db.products.insertOne( { name : "iPhone 7", Price : 900, company : "Apple"})
```

---

```
// product_review Collection

db.product_review.insertOne( { name : "Watch", comment: " Great Product" })
db.product_review.insertOne( { name : "Watch", comment: " AMAZING" })
db.product_review.insertOne( { name : "iPhone 7", comment: " Not bad" })
db.product_review.insertOne( { name : "iPhone 7", comment: " Expeinsive" })
db.product_review.insertOne( { name : "Galaxy Note9", comment: " Great Product" })
db.product_review.insertOne( { name : "Galaxy Note9", comment: " Great Product" })

// end of product_review collection.
```

---

The output that I am looking for is as the following. One Name and one or many comments without repeating the name with each comment. It should be like this.

```
{
    name: "iPhone 7", 
    Price: 900, 
    company: "Samsung", 
    comments :[ 
        {"comment": "Not bad"}, 
        {"comment": " Expeinsive"}
    ]
}
```

---

My current Code does not give me the comment, It gives me the name and price, and empty comment.

I found this code and tried to adopt it, but it can be work as I want

```
// map for products collection 

var mapproducts = function() {
    var output = {
        name: this.name, 
        Price :this.Price, 
        company:this.company, 
        comment:0
    }
    if (this.Price == 0) {
        output.name = this.name;
    }

    emit(this.name, output);
};

// map for product_review collection

var map_product_review = function() {
    emit(this.name, {
        name: this.name, 
        comment:this.comment, 
        Price:0, 
        company: 0
    });
};

// Reduce function. 
// I believe that the  "IF condition" has to be done, is specific ways

 var r = function(key, values) {    
     var outs = { name: 1,comment: 1, Price: 0,company:0};    

     values.forEach(function(v){       
         outs.name = v.name; 

         if (v.comment == 0) {            
             outs.Price = v.Price;
             outs.company = v.company;
         }
     });

     return outs; 
};




db.products.mapReduce(mapproducts, r, {out: {reduce: ‘Result’}})
db.product_review.mapReduce(map_product_review, r, {out: {reduce: 'Result'}})

db.Result.find().pretty()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882184/join-two-collections-with-mapreduce-in-mongodb

Comment: I tried that but it is duplicate the results in my code! Thanks

Comment: Did you try the `$lookup` pipeline: `db.products.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
       "from": "product_review",
       "localField": "name",
       "foreignField": "name",
       "as": "comments"  
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
       "comments": "$comments.comment" 
    } }
    
])`?

Comment: Yes, Thanks. But, I am looking for MAp/Reduce as the above.

Comment: Could anyone help me, please?